# How to receive frames from a frame server like Avisynth?

Tags: .net, windows

I have found it unusually hard to find any documentation on the technology behind frameserving. I'm not even sure if this has anything to do with DirectShow or not.

How can I receive video frames (ignoring audio) from a frame server like Avisynth in a .NET program? Anything with (links to) examples will be best, but even just a few words about how things fit together will be appreciated too.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, I’ve wondered that myself — I’m surprised there are no answers.

Comment: @Timwi I've since found AvisynthWrapper which exposes an API to request frames and sound from an Avisynth file. I don't know how it does this, but I wouldn't be surprised if this is different to the mechanism through which .avs files can be played through a DirectShow video player.

Answer (score 0):

In exactly the same way that you would open and get video frames from an AVI file.  Avisynth installs itself in such a way that the only difference an application sees between .avi and .avs files is the file extension itself.